# Adding Product ID to WHMCS Invoice

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, whmcs

I'm trying to add a product ID to my invoice in WHMCS and nothing seems to be working.  Here's what I have right now for that line of code:

```
<span class="title">{$LANG.invoicenumber}{*{else}{$LANG.proformainvoicenumber}{/if}*}{$invoicenum} - Service ID #{$invoiceitems.relid}</span><br />
```

This right here is specifically the part that I added in and isn't working:

```
 - Service ID #{$invoiceitems.relid}
```

When I run debug to see the different variables than be used it shows that `{$invoiceitems}` can be used to display items like this:

```
Array (2)
0 => Array (6)
  id => 1830
  type => Hosting
  relid => 801
  description => My Hosting Services - dsdjsjd....
  amount => $295.00 USD
  taxed =>
1 => Array (6)
  id => 1831
  type => PromoHosting
  relid => 801
  description => Promotional Code: FREETRIAL - $0.01 U...
  amount => $-294.99 USD
  taxed =>
```

What I'm trying to get is the number 801 so that the line displays like this:

**Invoice #7691 - Service ID #801**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code after Invoice # :

```
{if $invoiceitems|@count > 0}
Service ID: #{$invoiceitems[0].relid}
{/if}
```

May be you need to check $invoiceitems[0].type for being a domain or hosting be fore output the Service ID.

Answer (score 0):

`{$invoiceitems}` is the whole item array on the template page.
So when you try to reach by `{$invoiceitems.relid}`, won't give any result because you need to get the item within `{$invoiceitems}` array by index and then you can reach that property called relid.

I think iteration within array will solve your problem.

```
{foreach key=num item=singleitem from=$invoiceitems}
   {$singleitem.relid} // here you can reach the property.
{/foreach }
```